# Eclipse oxygen could not create the java virtual machine when starting tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-oxygen

I have change my JDK from 8 to 7. i also try changing the Xms and Xmx values...but no result. I even added (-vm
C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin) to the eclipse.ini file but no good results

```
-startup    
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: The eclipse.ini only sets values for the JVM that runs Eclipse - it is nothing to do with the Tomcat JVM.

Comment: ok. but am really confused on how to resolve this problem on tomcat 7. Any solution ?

Comment: Which version of Java is being used to run Tomcat?

Comment: C:\Users\anyatt>java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: And what are the contents of the Console view when Tomcat fails to launch?

Comment: instead wornings into console and the are to long to being posted.  but when i start the sever, i got a pop-up saying:  ERROR:COULD NOT CREATE THE JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE;   ERROR: A FATAL EXCEPTION HAS OCCURED. PROGRAM WILL EXIT

Comment: @solo You need to update your post with full details of the error. Nobody can solve your problem if you don't show the failure.